# Access Version History and Approval from Word Macro

Tags: workflow, word, approval-process, vba

Our word document templates include a table that includes a version history and a second table with the list of approvers of the document.

I would like to populate these tables from a VBA macro that runs when the document is opened. I already found out that I can access the rows from a Document Library via `ActiveDocument.ContentTypeProperties`.

But is there also a way to access SharePoint related information like the version history and workflow information from the macro?